# Run post-build event without build?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, post-build-event

I have a web-application (using Visual Studio 2013) where most parts are loaded via plugins.
During development I have post-build events on all the plugin projects to copy themself into the plugin folder of the main appliction so they are loaded automatically.

This works fine when building the plugin, but often I just change assets (e.g. CSS) and do not require the plugin to be rebuilt, just the asstes copied again, which would be much faster.

**Is there a way to execute the post-build events without rebuilding the plugin project?**

Or is there another way I can trigger such copy script from within Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you find solution to this question? I am also looking in similar lines.

Comment: @Digital_Reality No, but I do not have a real problem with this anymore as the projects in question are mostly so small they build really fast...